# Fill NA values in a data frame according to another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have two data frames that almost have the same samples. `df1` has many samples and it contains almost all the samples that are found in `df2`, apart from 2 or 3 samples.

In `df1` there is a column, lets say it's the gender, that has `NA` values. Those gender values are found in `df2`.

I want to fill the NA values for each sample in `df1` according to `df2`, for the shared samples between them.

How can I do that? especially that `df1` is much bigger than `df2` and the samples are not in the same order.

So for example let's say this is `df1`:

```
       samples       gender
1        Pt8           NA
2        Pt102         NA
3        Pt87          NA
4        Pt1           NA
```

And this is `df2`:

```
      subject_id     gender
1        Pt1          male
2        Pt102        male
3        Pt6          female
4        Pt8          male
```

So I just fill in the NA values that are in `df1` according to the sample name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use a join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, gender := fcoalesce(as.character(gender), i.gender), 
   on= .(samples = subject_id)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: Please see comments (removed wrong first answer):

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2 %>% 
            rename_with(~colnames(df1))) %>% 
  arrange(gender) %>% 
  distinct(samples, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  semi_join(df1, by="samples") %>% 
  mutate(samples = factor(samples, levels = df1$samples)) %>%
  arrange(samples)

  samples gender
4     Pt8   male
2   Pt102   male
3    Pt87   <NA>
1     Pt1   male
```

Comment: But what about `Pt1` and `Pt8` ? they are found in both data frames, its just the order that differs.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Sorry I did not grasp at the start. Here is an update version.